# How to check if image failed to load?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I wanted to know if there was anyway, we can know the image was not loaded in the screen (roPosterScreen, roSpringBoard, or any screen). What I mean is, I set an image url in any of the screen and the image was deleted from the server, then can we check if the image is still there or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check manually with `roUrlTransfer`. For definitive answer, ask in Roku dev.forum

Answer (score 0):

I've not found any callbacks/events to get that information from the various screens. In case an image is not present, it just falls back to the error image you can configure for some of the screens.